# AWS Storage Volume Gateway - Cached volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, aws-storage-gateway

AWS documentation clearly mentions Gateway Stored Volumes- "This data is **asynchronously** backed up to S3 in the form of Amazon EBS snapshots."

But there is no mention how the Storage Volume Gateway Cached volumes data is replicated - Aync/Async snapshots ?
The documentation reads

> "Cached volumes let you use Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) as your primary data storage **while retaining** frequently accessed data locally in your storage gateway."
>
> "In the cached volumes solution, AWS Storage Gateway stores all your on-premises application data in a storage volume in Amazon S3. "

Can someone explain

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Storage Volume Gateway Cached mode, data is written to S3 and cached locally for frequently accessed files.

Cached volumes let you use Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) as your primary data storage while retaining frequently accessed data locally in your storage gateway. Cached volumes minimize the need to scale your on-premises storage infrastructure, while still providing your applications with low-latency access to their frequently accessed data. You can create storage volumes up to 32 TiB in size and attach to them as iSCSI devices from your on-premises application servers. Your gateway stores data that you write to these volumes in Amazon S3 and retains recently read data in your on-premises storage gateway's cache and upload buffer storage.

Cached volumes can range from 1 GiB to 32 TiB in size and must be rounded to the nearest GiB. Each gateway configured for cached volumes can support up to 32 volumes for a total maximum storage volume of 1,024 TiB (1 PiB).

In the cached volumes solution, AWS Storage Gateway stores all your on-premises application data in a storage volume in Amazon S3.

[Cached Volume Architecture](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/StorageGatewayConcepts.html)

Answer (score 1):

So based on the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/StorageGatewayConcepts.html#volume-gateway-concepts) its asynchronous by nature.

> As your applications write data to the storage volumes in AWS, the
>   gateway initially stores the data on the on-premises disks referred to
>   as cache storage before uploading the data to Amazon S3. The cache
>   storage acts as the on-premises durable store for data that is waiting
>   to upload to Amazon S3 from the upload buffer.

Comment: Based on everything (including the diagram) - it has to be Async (what else could the 'buffer' be for). Then the other part of the question arises - where do you read it from- S3 or Local. The diagram does not exactly show - suggests you are reading everything locally (not just the 'frequently accessed' data).